# How to run swift in vscode?

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code

I am new at swift programming language and i am going to start . before starting i setup the visual studio and wrote just print("Hello, World!") . but after i pressed run without debugging it tells the following window can not start debugging because no configuration has been provide

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I’m doing same thing - simple one line print…

I installed Debian - bullseye. Installed Swift, installed vscode.

In vscode I use the Swift extension curated by apple. That extension needs the extension CodeLLDB.

When you click Run, I select LLDB not node or anything else.

Works well except when I try to run and debug I’m getting an ELF issue seems something is 32bit and something is 64. Debian is 64, Swift —version works!?

How do I figure out what is 32?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. Uninstalling and verifying 64 bit did install worked